# Root spread for Lime and Sweet Chestnut trees

Tags: trees, roots

At the end of my garden I have some Lime and Sweet Chestnut trees.
I am wondering what the root spread can be. These trees are very mature, about 80 ft high.

Answer (score 2):

Current thinking is that the significant roots of the tree will extend to at least the end of the branches that are farthest from the main trunk  (the drip line). Finer roots will extend out even farther depending on soil type and species of tree.

See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1555/499) for details